# XSLT count() is not working

Tags: xslt, attributes, count

I'm trying to do the count where XML/Attributes/Attribute[@Type='ComplexAttr']. If it is present then do this else do something else. However, count is always zero. Can someone tell what I'm missing. 
Also can someone guide me on how to improve the last part of the xslt where I'm using many 
xsl:if statements.
Thanks in Advance.

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:key name="type" match="Attribute" use="Type"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Data Schema="XML A">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="XML/Attributes/Attribute[generate-id() = generate-id(key('type', Type)[1])]">
        <xsl:sort select="Type" order="descending"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
      <errorCodes>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="XML/Attributes/Attribute" mode="errors"/>
      </errorCodes>
    </Data>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Attribute">
    <xsl:variable name="compType">
      <xsl:value-of select="count(XML/Attributes/Attribute[Type='ComplexAttr'])"/>
    </xsl:variable>  />
    <!--<xsl:value-of select="count($compType)"/>-->
    <xsl:if test="Type!='ComplexAttr'">
      <Attributes type="{Type}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('type',Type)" mode="out"/>
        <xsl:if test="Type='common'">
          <Collection id="" name="test">
            <ComplexAttr refId="0">
              <MaskValue />
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$compType > 0">
                     <xsl:apply-templates select="key('type','ComplexAttr')" mode="out"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                  <Attr id="" name="Color" value="000"/>
                  <Attr id="" name="Size" value="0010"/>
                  <Attr id="" name="UPC" value=""/>
                  <Attr id="" name="Style#" value=""/>
                  <Attr id="" name="Exclude" value=""/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
            </ComplexAttr>
          </Collection>
        </xsl:if>
      </Attributes>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Attribute" mode="out">
    <Attr id="{id}" name="{Name}" value="{Value}"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Attribute[Type='ComplexAttr']" mode="out">
    <Attr id="{id}" name="{Name}" value="{Value}"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Attribute" mode="errors">
    <xsl:if test="Name['Buyer ID' or 'Coordinator ID' or 'Retail' or 
            'Master Pack Qty' or 'Master Pack Height' or 'Master Pack Length' or 'Master Pack Weight' or
            'Master Pack Width' or 'Product Description' or 'PO Cost' or 'GTIN' or 'Vendor Model'] and Value=''">
    <errorCode>"value for <xsl:value-of select="Name"/> is missing."</errorCode>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<XML>
    <Attributes>
        <Attribute>
            <id>5</id>
            <Name>Buyer ID</Name>
            <Type>common</Type>
            <Value>Lee</Value>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute>
            <id>331</id>
            <Name>Enviornment</Name>
            <Type>common</Type>
            <Value>Development</Value>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute>
            <id>79</id>
            <Name>Retail</Name>
            <Type>common</Type>
            <Value></Value>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute>
            <id>402</id>
            <Name>Gender</Name>
            <Type>category</Type>
            <Value>Men</Value>
        </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
         <id>1197</id> 
         <Name>UPC</Name> 
         <Type>ComplexAttr</Type> 
         <Value>Testing</Value> 
         <Path /> 
    </Attribute>
</Attributes>
```

OutPut:
As you can see it is not giving me the expected output. It should be Attributes/Attribute[Type='common']/Collection/ComplexAttr/ and I'm getting the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data Schema="XML A">
  <Attributes type="common">
    <Attr id="5" name="Buyer ID" value="Lee" />
    <Attr id="331" name="Enviornment" value="Development" />
    <Attr id="79" name="Retail" value="" />
    <Attr id="41" name="PlusShip" value="False" />
    <Collection id="" name="test">
      <ComplexAttr refId="0">
        <MaskValue />
        <Attr id="" name="Color" value="000" />
        <Attr id="" name="Size" value="0010" />
        <Attr id="" name="UPC" value="" />
        <Attr id="" name="Style#" value="" />
        <Attr id="" name="Exclude" value="" />
      </ComplexAttr>
    </Collection>
  </Attributes>
  <Attributes type="category">
    <Attr id="402" name="Gender" value="Men" />
    <Attr id="433" name="HeelHeight" value="" />
  </Attributes>
  <errorCodes>
    <errorCode>"value for Retail is missing."</errorCode>
  </errorCodes>
</Data>
```

Comment: You say "I'm trying to do the count where XML/Attributes/Attribute[@Type='ComplexAttr']." I can't find that code anywhere in your sample.

Comment: @Micheal Kay. I was making a change in my code as per my discussion with @Iwburk. I have uploaded the updated XSLT. Let me know if you see something. Thanks

Comment: @Michael - Right, but he does have `/XML/Attributes/Attribute[Type='ComplexAttr']` which is what I think was meant

Comment: I've posted an updated answer. Hope this works better for you.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation of the problem and an easy solution. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
>   <xsl:template match="Attribute">     
>    <xsl:variable name="compType">       
>      <xsl:value-of select="count(XML/Attributes/Attribute[Type='ComplexAttr'])"/>
>
>    </xsl:variable>
> ```

**The problem is here**.

An `Attribute` element doesn't have a child named `XML`, so the text node that is child of the above variable has the value '0'.

**You want**:

```
<xsl:variable name="compType" 
     select="count(/XML/Attributes/Attribute[Type='ComplexAttr'])"/>
```

**Explanation**: The problem was due to using a relative XPath expression instead of an absolute one.

Comment: Thanks for your response and explaining the problem. I did the work around like this <xsl:choose><xsl:when test="count(//Attribute[Type='ComplexAttr']) > 0"><xsl:apply-templates select="key('type','ComplexAttr')" mode="out"/></xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise> do this....</xsl:choose>. I will still accept your answer since you point out the mistake I was making and provided the correct resolution. Thanks

Comment: @JohnXsl: You are welcome. BTW, it is recommended to avoid the use of `//` always when possible -- it generally results in low performance.

Comment: Thanks. I have made the change as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

> However, count is always zero. Can
>   someone tell what I'm missing.

**Answer #1:** You're counting the number of `Attribute` elements having an attribute named `Type` whose value is `ComplexAttr`:

```
<xsl:when test="count(//Attribute[@Type='ComplexAttr']) > 0">
```

But you should be counting the number of `Attribute` elements having a child element named `Type` whose value is `ComplexAttr`:

```
<xsl:when test="count(//Attribute[Type='ComplexAttr']) > 0">
```

Making only this change to your XSLT causes the test to pass.

> Also can someone guide me on how to
>   improve the last part of the xslt
>   where I'm using many xsl:if
>   statements.

**Answer #2:** I would combine each of those conditions into one:

```
<xsl:if test="Name['Retail' or 'Environment' or 
    'Master Pack Qty' or 'Master Pack Height'] and Value=''">
    <errorCode>"value for <xsl:value-of select="Name"/> is missing."</errorCode>
</xsl:if>
```

Each situation is handled identically, so there's no need to keep them separate.

This simplified stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:key name="type" match="Attribute" use="Type"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Attribute">
      <xsl:if test="Name['Buyer ID' or 'Coordinator ID' or 'Retail' or 
            'Master Pack Qty' or 'Master Pack Height' or 'Master Pack Length' or
            'Master Pack Weight' or 'Master Pack Width' or 'Product Description' or 
            'PO Cost' or 'GTIN' or 'Vendor Model'] and Value=''">
          <errorCode>"value for <xsl:value-of select="Name"/> is missing."</errorCode>
      </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces the following output (on your input):

```
<errorCode>"value for Retail is missing."</errorCode>
```

Comment: @Iwburk thanks for your response. Individually the above might work but if I plug it in the xslt it will still evaluate all elements and produce the list for non-required element as well. However, if I do this (Name='Buyer ID' or Name='Coordinator ID' or Name='Retail' ... or Name='Vendor Model') and Value=''") then it works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to count: `key('type','ComplexAttr')` gives you the desired `Attribute` elements with `Type` child equal to `'ComplexAttr'` because `xsl:key` declaration.

If you want to output some default elements when there is no such `Attribute`, then use:

```
<xsl:template match="Attribute[Type='ComplexAttr']"/>
<xsl:template match="Attribute[Type='common']">
    <Attributes type="common">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('type','common')" mode="out"/>
        <Collection id="" name="test">
            <ComplexAttr refId="0">
                <MaskValue />
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('type','ComplexAttr')"
                                     mode="out"/>
            </ComplexAttr>
        </Collection>
    </Attributes>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Attribute[Type='common']
                              [not(key('type','ComplexAttr'))]"
              priority="1">
    <Attributes type="common">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('type','common')" mode="out"/>
        <Collection id="" name="test">
            <ComplexAttr refId="0">
                <MaskValue />
                    <Attr id="" name="Color" value="000"/>
                    <Attr id="" name="Size" value="0010"/>
                    <Attr id="" name="UPC" value=""/>
                    <Attr id="" name="Style#" value=""/>
                    <Attr id="" name="Exclude" value=""/>
            </ComplexAttr>
        </Collection>
    </Attributes>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Attribute">
    <Attributes type="{Type}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('type',Type)" mode="out"/>
    </Attributes>
</xsl:template>
```

**Note**: `@priority` to not rely on recovery mechanism. Just for fun, more pull style.